# Rotation precision issues

Tags: html, canvas, rotation

I have lines on my canvas that i'm drawing with pattern image. The user can zoom in as much as he wants.

my lines have some world values, which is converted to pixels every draw.

The problem is when the user go deep and the line pixels starting to become high negative/positive, such as -40000 and 50000. When the line is with a small rotation we see unexpected results such as shown in the demo i created here.

In the demo we can see the main canvas we are drawing into and a small canvas that represents my pattern. And we can see in the main canvas that the pattern is not correct

```js
// JavaScript source code

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
var ctx = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');

var center = {
  x: mainCanvas.width / 2,
  y: mainCanvas.height / 2
};



var angle = 0;


// Creating the pattern image
var imgCtx = imgLine.getContext('2d');
imgCtx.strokeStyle = 'red';
imgCtx.lineWidth = 2;
imgCtx.beginPath();
imgCtx.moveTo(0, imgLine.height / 2);
imgCtx.lineTo(imgLine.width, imgLine.height / 2);
imgCtx.stroke();
imgCtx.beginPath();
imgCtx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
imgCtx.moveTo(imgLine.width * 0.3, 0);
imgCtx.lineTo(imgLine.width * 0.3, imgLine.height);
imgCtx.stroke();
imgCtx.beginPath();
imgCtx.strokeStyle = 'green';
imgCtx.moveTo(imgLine.width * 0.8, 0);
imgCtx.lineTo(imgLine.width * 0.8, imgLine.height);
imgCtx.stroke();


ctx.fillStyle = ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.createPattern(imgLine, "repeat");

onDataChanged(true);


function rotateAtPoint(p_objContext, center, p_dblAngle) {
  p_objContext.translate(center.x, center.y);
  p_objContext.rotate(p_dblAngle);
  p_objContext.translate(-center.x, -center.y);
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, mainCanvas.width, mainCanvas.height);

  var lineWidth = imgLine.height * scale;
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;

  ctx.save();
  rotateAtPoint(ctx, center, angle);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(center.x, center.y);
  ctx.lineTo(center.x + lineLength, center.y);
  ctx.stroke();

  //ctx.fillRect(center.x,center.y + 30, lineLength, lineWidth);
  ctx.restore();
}


function onDataChanged(skipDraw) {
  scale = parseFloat(txtFactor.value);
  center.x = parseFloat(txtX.value);
  center.y = parseFloat(txtY.value);
  lineLength = parseFloat(txtLineLength.value);
  angle = parseFloat(txtAngle.value);
  draw();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="padding:10px">
    Angle:
    <input id="txtAngle" type="number" value="0.001" min="0" step="0.0001" max="360" onchange="onDataChanged()" />X:
    <input id="txtX" type="number" value="-40000" min="-1000000" step="1" max="1000000" onchange="onDataChanged()" />Y:
    <input id="txtY" type="number" value="150" min="-1000000" step="1" max="1000000" onchange="onDataChanged()" />Length:
    <input id="txtLineLength" type="number" value="100000" min="0" step="5" max="5000000" onchange="onDataChanged()" />Factor:
    <input id="txtFactor" type="number" value="1" min="0" step="0.1" max="500" onchange="onDataChanged()" />
  </div>

  <div id="canvasesDiv">
    <canvas id="mainCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black; margin-right: 20px; background-color: lightgray; "></canvas>
    <canvas id="imgLine" width="16" height="16" style="border: 1px solid black; margin-right: 20px;background-color:lightgreen"></canvas>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Anyone has any idea what to do ?

Cutting the line to only visible parts is not good to me because this problem is also reproduced in WebGL - which is weird cause the draw engine is different, and there the data is already in the buffers.

Comment: SVG (scalable vector graphic) to the rescue?

Comment: No.. I'm too deep inside in the project. Changing is not acceptable in this stage. and anyway, this problem somehow occurs in the WebGL as well. I think it is a problem with the browser. IN firefox it is working well

Comment: Reported the [bug in chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=438213&thanks=438213&ts=1417529687). But would be glad to hear some ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, and some solution, hope it will help someone.

The problem is the number of the repeats for the texture (both in canvas and webgl).

When the line is long, means that the pattern need to repeat itself allot, in some point it's loosing it. Maybe some overflow problem.

My solution is to cut my line to smaller segments, this way each segment will be shorter, and the repeat number of the pattern will be less, and restart every segment. (of course i'm handl

This is solving the problem,
But i'm still waiting for chrome to answer my [post](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=438213&thanks=438213&ts=1417529687).

Answer (score 0):

The strange result you have is the result of a two factors :

• You are defining a green css background on the pattern canvas : it won't show when you use it  as a pattern, which is the expected behavior.

• You are starting the line way out of the canvas, which seems to create rounding issues in Chrome. The issue does not show in Firefox, but on the other hand it seems Firefox is rounding the angle, since it does not even attempt to rotate the pattern below a given threshold.

So it seems FF and Chrome make a different bet : Chrome tries to respect the pattern angle (and fails) and FF just ignores it.

Comment: - I set the background just for viewing.. I know it is not showing in the main canvas. - The line points are the way they should. i know they are way outside the canvas. you could see in my question that the user zoomed in and causes this case. The question is if i can solve it without touching the coordinates of the line. BTW rounding the angle is not solving the issue in chrome